# GetNextID() - method in C#

Tags: c#, sql

How to execute this T-SQL command through a c# method so that I can get the next ID of a Table?

```
declare @IDColumnName as varchar(150)
declare @TableName as varchar(150)
declare @SQL as nvarchar(1000)
declare @returns as int

set @IDColumnName = 'ID'
set @TableName = 'User'
set @returns = -1

set @SQL = 'select MAX([' + @IDColumnName + ']) from [' + @TableName + ']'
--print @SQL

EXEC @returns = sp_executesql @SQL

--print @returns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar question. [AutoIncrement fields on databases without autoincrement field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526460/autoincrement-fields-on-databases-without-autoincrement-field)

[Here is my answer with working solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526460/autoincrement-fields-on-databases-without-autoincrement-field/533407#533407)

Answer (score 3):

Note that this is a blatant race condition unless you take a key-range lock. Why not use `IDENTITY`? But if you `SELECT` the value, you should be able use use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

Also; if you don't white-list the tables, that is a SQL injection risk.

Comment: Use a serializable transaction, and accept the blocking. Anything else and you have a race-condition. Identity is a lot cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

better to use identity other create UDF and put the code in this UDF and call it by using Executescalar method.