# NHibernate, Pivot-table and/or GetNextID()

Tags: nhibernate

Can I use pivot tables with NHibernate?

Can I write 
`ID id = new Transaction().GetNextID("[TableName]", "[IDColumnName]")`-like codes to increment IDs with NHibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Auto Increment Ids**
There are auto-increment id generators available for all databases supported by NHibernate. See [generator](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) in the reference documentation.

To use an auto-increment Id property, map it as follows and leave the Id value as the default (0) when creating new entities.

```
<id name="Id" >
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

You can even roll your own generator by implementing `NHibernate.Id.IIdentifierGenerator`. However, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526460/autoincrement-fields-on-databases-without-autoincrement-field) for a discussion on why you should use the database native auto-increment mechanism.

**Pivot Tables**
NHibernate has no specific support for Pivot tables. That said, you can map the results of any SQL query to objects using a result transformer. The target object does not need to be mapped, and the columns must match the properties.

[Named SQL](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-namedqueries) queries can be defined in your mapping files. You can also use [native SQL](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql) queries directly. Both types of query support named and positional parameters.

```
var list = session.GetNamedQuery("query-name")
    .SetResultTransformer( Transformers.AliasToBean<Foo>())
    .SetString("name", "foo")
    .List<Foo>();

var list = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE A=? and B=?")
    .SetString(0, "foo")
    .SetInt(1, 42)
    .SetResultTransformer( Transformers.AliasToBean<Foo>())
    .List<Foo>();
```

If you defined a view for a pivot query, you could define a readonly mapped class for it with `mutable="false"`.

**Result Transformers**

A number of result transformers are available, including:

- Transformers.**ToList** Returns a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) of values for each row.
- Transformers.**AliasToEntityMap** Creates a [map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) from column names to values for each row.
- Transformers.**AliasToBean()** Creates an object of the nominated type per row and sets its properties with the value from the column of the same name.

Comment: You don't even need a named query (which is good practice, but looks like overhead to a noob), you just can execute any SQL query directly.