# Get SqlConnection from Nhibernate 3.3

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to use Pivot with a named query with nhibernate 3.3 and use it in a GridView.

I saw on [NHibernate, Pivot-table and/or GetNextID()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290148/nhibernate-pivot-table-and-or-getnextid) that I can use result transformer but I can't predict what will be the fields. (So a bean isn't possible I think, and I need to have named column)

So the best solution is to use a named query and put it in a DataTable.

Is there a easy way to get the data and put it in a DataTable. A method would be to retrieve the SqlConnection from nhibernate and use it to retrieve the data returned by the stored procedure. But does someone how to do that ?

Regards

Comment: welll ... thank you that was pretty easy but i didn't find this information on the internet. can you post an answer so i flag it as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NHibernates ISession interface has property `Connection` which gives the underlying ADO.NET connction object.