# Django atomic update based on filter result

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a model that looks like

```
class order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(some_user)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

number is supposed to be an incremented (+1) amount based on the total number of existing orders for a user. I've looked into F() objects before but from what I can gather they can only be used for updating a field thats pre-existing. Is there a way to increment that the number by 1 without having a to worry about two orders have the same number?

Comment: Are you trying to use the number field as a faux-pk per-user?  Your use of ForeignKey here indicates that you're confused about things.  Are you creating a new instance with the +1 value, or updating an existing instance?

Comment: I suppose it looks like a pk in the sense that it's supposed to be unique amount orders with the same user, but it is not unique for all orders. There can be multiple orders with the same number but different users.. It's just meant to be sequential number of all the existing orders (+1). So on save it would be something like order(user=some_user, number=order.objects.filter(user=some_user).count()+1).save().

Comment: Also this is only done when creating a new instance. It never gets changed.

Comment: As I understand it, you want something like `insert into myapp_order(user_id, number) values (7, (select max(number)+1 from myapp_order where user_id=7))`.  Unfortunately, I don't think django has any support for nested queries, nor do I know how feasible it is to hand-craft an insert query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as Django doesn't support creating atomic sequences, my conclusion is to use Redis for atomic counting and just query that in order to get the latest order value.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to get the total number of orders per user. Then it'll be better for you to first create a many to many field between `user` and `order`. Then you can get the count required by simply instantiating a given user(say `userone`) and then calling,

```
userone.order_set.count()
```

Comment: Would a ManyToManyField make sense in this situation? The way I thought about it was a user has many orders, but a single order can only ever have one user, that's why I used a foreign key instead. I can just do a .count() and save like I said in the above comment, but that doesn't make it atomic and opens the possibility that another order was saved before the current order was saved cause two orders with the same user to have the same order number.

Comment: This exact API is already available with the FK, if it's set to auth.User.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to create a sequence for each user.  You can use a database sequence ([postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html)) or something like this:

```
class UserMetadata(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    next_order_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

And each time you create a new order you use the `next_order_number` field and increment it by one (using `UPDATE ... LAST_INSERT_ID(next_order_number+1)...` in MySQL. See: [AutoIncrement fields on databases without autoincrement field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526460/autoincrement-fields-on-databases-without-autoincrement-field/4921239#4921239) ).

As far as I know Django have no built in support for creating such sequences in an atomic way.  This might be a good start: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/304/

Answer (score 0):

If it was about just incrementation of number, then using a [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#autofield) might be enough, but incrementation of a value prior to some other data is not easy to handle on model definiton.

One possible way is overriding **save()** method.

[Check here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) for basic django saving procedure. And [here for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) how to override default save method. You may try to check if related save action is for a new insertion or an update for an existing record, and if it is insertion, you may set a unique number to that record for specified user.