# SQL Server AutoIncrement varying by value of another field

Tags: sql-server-2008, auto-increment

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I'd like to have a table (already having a primary key on 2 columns) with a third column which is an autoincrement based on one of the two columns part of the primary key.

In other terms, I would like **when adding a new record to the table**, have an autoincrement file `AIfield` automatically incremented as follows:

```
  PK1 PK2  AIfield 
  ------------------
  1   A     1
  1   B     2
  1   C     3
  2   A     1
  2   B1    2
  2   B2    3
  2   C1    4
```

where PK1 and PK2 are the two fields of the primary key.

I do not want to use the obvious `MAX(Afield)+1` approach, since it's very likely that I have to do concurrent inserts for the same PK1 - which would sooner or later create duplicates in AIfield for the same PK1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To everybody: the problem is NOT getting a select with a unique number, it is concurrency safe updating a column of the table with a value. So all the answers just a SELECT ROW_NUMBER() are NOT answer to the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, an approach could be creating a unique Index on PK1 and AIfield

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [test] ON [Table] 
(
[AIfield] ASC,
[PK1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,  
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and handling violations of uniqueness

```
DECLARE @inserted BIT=0
DECLARE @AIfield BIGINT
SELECT @AIfield=MAX(AIfield)+1 FROM Table WHERE PK1=@PK1
WHILE @inserted=0
BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
  INSERT INTO Table(AIfield,PK1,PK2)
  SELECT  @AIfield,@PK1,@PK2
  SET @inserted=1
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER()=2601
     BEGIN
     SET @AIfield=@AIfield+1
     END
    ELSE SET @inserted=1
 END CATCH
END
```

I wonder if there is an approach more SQL native, though

Answer (score 2):

```
select pk1,pk2,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pk1,pk2 order by (select 0)) as AIfield
from yourtable
```

Comment: is this going to be concurrent-insert safe?

Comment: can you give me little more details?

Comment: what you can do is,put the above query results into a table variable or temp table and then do the process whatever you need to

Comment: The issue is that I could have clients trying to insert different records for the same PK1 at the same time. This would result into having same Row_number() suggest the same AIfield, therefore creating duplicates. it is more or less the same issue as MAX+1. I know I might post process to check and fix duplicates, but it's not a neat approach - something more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526460/autoincrement-fields-on-databases-without-autoincrement-field)

Comment: when you are querying this table to export data to text file,you can use this query I guess.At that moment this wil work.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
Select PK1, PK2, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PK1 order by PK1, PK2) as AIfield
From yourtable
```