# MySQL/MariaDB update counter group by

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How can I update a `number` column such that it counts 1,2,3,4,... and then restarts from 1 again when another column `booking_id` changes?

Here's what I've got so far:

```sql
SET @pos := 0;
SET @last := 0;

UPDATE booking_segments
SET number = (SELECT @pos := if(booking_id = @last, @pos + 1, 1)), @last := booking_id
where 1
ORDER BY booking_id, pickup_time_utc;
```

I think something like this should work, but I don't know how to weasel that `@last := booking_id` bit in there without creating a syntax error. If MySQL and a comma operator like JS, I could do it but I'm not sure what else might be valid inside the `SET` block.

---

I figured something out, but is there a less ghetto way of doing this?

```sql
SET @pos := 0;
SET @last := 0;

UPDATE booking_segments
SET number = @tmp := (SELECT @pos := if(booking_id = @last, @pos + 1, 1)),
    number = @last := booking_id, 
    number = @tmp
where 1
ORDER BY booking_id,pickup_time_utc ;
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dnid.png) if you're having trouble picturing this.

```
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | booking_id | number | pickup_time_utc     |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2          | 1      | 2015-02-22 18:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 7  | 2          | 2      | 2015-02-23 04:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 8  | 5          | 1      | 2015-06-06 21:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 9  | 5          | 2      | 2015-06-07 08:15:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 10 | 6          | 1      | 2015-04-11 15:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 11 | 6          | 2      | 2015-04-12 05:30:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 16 | 8          | 1      | 2015-07-28 08:20:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 17 | 8          | 2      | 2015-07-28 10:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 18 | 9          | 1      | 2015-07-01 15:50:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 19 | 10         | 1      | 2015-09-13 06:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 20 | 11         | 1      | 2015-08-01 23:30:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 21 | 11         | 2      | 2015-08-02 07:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 22 | 12         | 1      | 2015-08-08 20:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 23 | 13         | 1      | 2015-09-05 21:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 24 | 14         | 1      | 2015-09-19 20:30:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 25 | 15         | 1      | 2015-08-29 21:15:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 26 | 16         | 1      | 2015-09-10 03:15:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 37 | 16         | 2      | 2015-09-10 08:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 28 | 17         | 1      | 2015-08-12 22:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 29 | 18         | 1      | 2015-08-11 08:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 30 | 19         | 1      | 2015-08-15 21:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 32 | 20         | 1      | 2016-06-09 09:05:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 31 | 20         | 2      | 2016-06-10 12:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 33 | 21         | 1      | 2015-09-10 05:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 34 | 22         | 1      | 2015-09-10 02:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 35 | 22         | 2      | 2015-09-10 04:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 36 | 22         | 3      | 2015-09-10 06:45:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 38 | 23         | 1      | 2015-09-10 04:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 39 | 23         | 2      | 2015-09-10 09:45:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 40 | 24         | 1      | 2015-09-10 04:30:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 41 | 24         | 2      | 2015-09-10 06:45:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 67 | 38         | 1      | 2016-01-02 16:20:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 68 | 38         | 2      | 2016-01-03 07:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 69 | 38         | 3      | 2016-01-03 10:00:00 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
```

The version I'm currently using is 10.1.14-MariaDB.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? In general, people dont like images on SO. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I found this question with the solution. I think it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152790/sql-server-autoincrement-varying-by-value-of-another-field

Comment: MariaDB started supporting [Window/Analytic function since version 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions); unfortunately your version is slightly old; if you can upgrade, you can write this query in a "less ghetto" way...

Comment: Yeah, I think I can upgrade as long as 10.2 isn't too backwards incompatible with 10.1 :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MariaDB started supporting Window/Analytic functions since version 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) ; so if you can upgrade, you can utilize [`Row_Number()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/) functionality.

In a Derived Table, we can first fetch the "row number" for every row, on a partition of `booking_id` ordered by `pickup_time_utc` in ascending order. We can then join back to the main table, in order to update the `number` column. The query would be simply the following:

```
UPDATE booking_segments AS bs
       JOIN (SELECT id,
                    Row_number()
                      OVER (
                        partition BY booking_id
                        ORDER BY pickup_time_utc ASC) AS rn
             FROM   booking_segments) AS dt
         ON dt.id = bs.id
SET    bs.number = dt.rn
```