# Concurrency concerns with triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I needed to create an auto-increment column based on the value of another column and I made the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[setPosition]
ON [dbo].[myTable]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @maxPosition SMALLINT
    DECLARE @templateName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @id INT

    SELECT @id=id FROM inserted
    SELECT @templateName=templateName FROM inserted
    SELECT @maxPosition=ISNULL(MAX(position),0) FROM [myTable] WHERE [templateName]=@templateName 

    UPDATE [myTable]
    SET position = @maxPosition+1 WHERE id=@id  
END
```

It works but I have a concern. Is there any chance I have double numbers? If, for example, it runs in an environment with many users. I have a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152790/sql-server-autoincrement-varying-by-value-of-another-field) where to ensure the previous concern does a loop check for error having first created an index and updates when there is no error. But I believe that such a check is futile because as far as I know the triggers run in isolated transaction mode.

UPDATED

The data after inserts would be like (id is an auto-increment column)

[image]

Comment: When you do `SELECT @somevariable=somecolumn FROM inserted` you have already gone wrong and lost the game. Trigger works on multiple rows at the same time, so the logic here will only assign one row. Just don't do this in a trigger, you can use a VIEW where you do a ROW_NUMBER() to assign the numbers instead

Comment: A trigger is not the right tool here, especially one that suffers from the [most common trigger bug](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: @siggemannen Could you explain a case where we could have more than one rows. I can't think of such a case in this specific situation.

Comment: `insert into myTable (id) values (1), (2), (3)`

Comment: OK. I see. But there is no possibility the front-end software to issue sql statement like this.

Comment: That doesn't matter, @nonlinear . That your application doesn't *today* doesn't mean it won't **tomorrow** or someone else will issue that `INSERT`. If you were selling a car and it had no seat belts, would your response to someone asking about that be "well you're not driving it right now, so it doesn't matter it's not safe."?

Comment: In my opinion, you would be better off with a `SEQUENCE` or something.

Comment: @Thom I won't argue with you but you give something you get something in this life. After all, the program is solely under my control.

Comment: So as the sole contributor write your code *properly* so future you doesn't regret past you's decisions.

Comment: The app may be under your control today but maybe not tomorrow. As to whether or not you care about the next person is your call but I personally take pride in my work.

Comment: An alternative is to request the next number form the software code issuing an sql for that reason. But the principle is to do in the database as much as you can in it and as little as you get away from it

Comment: So at the end please give me a more safe alternative or response to question of this post if it is safe for double numbers or I have to do it with the error check

Comment: I understand and take into account the above concerns but firstly they don't make sense unless something alternative is suggested and secondly the post is not about the principles of good programming but it is very specific please.

Comment: I think it would be a lot clearer if you showed some sample data and the expected results after the insert(s)

Comment: *"firstly they don't make sense unless something alternative is suggested"* ... "[In my opinion, you would be better off with a `SEQUENCE` or something.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77408612/concurrency-concerns-with-triggers?noredirect=1#comment136466526_77408612)" why ignore my suggestion?

Comment: I saw that but could you be more specific please. Thanks

Comment: [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @ThomA I've already dealt with it. But first, there is already an auto-increment column and as we know you can't have a second one and even if it didn't exist how would you apply it to the specific problem that we don't want to generalize to the whole table?

Comment: A `SEQUENCE` isn't an `IDENTITY`, @nonlinear . They are different tools that fulfil similar tasks.

Comment: @ThomA you are right. I will examine it although I can't immediately imagine how it would be used in this particular case

Comment: Have a  `SEQUENCE`  for each template.

Comment: I thought it. When a template created then I have to issue a CREATE SEQUENCE 'seqTemplateName' sql. And when a new record is inserted in the myTable then I have to check the 'templateName' to get the next sequence number from 'seqTemplateName'. And they should be deleted when one 'templateName' is deleted This is a lot effort. But again shouldn't I use a trigger? Or should I run these sql statements from the front-end code of the software?

Comment: Also in this particular case the templates that the users will create will not be many (at most 5 or 6) but in cases where you may have thousands and you have to create the corresponding sequences, how much would this affect the performance of the sql server?

Comment: And what do you want to happen if a row is deleted? Maybe you should juts use `ROW_NUMBER` when you query the data.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't care about that. If a record is deleted I am aware that there will be a gap and it is something that does not cause us a problem in the business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **much better** solutions for what you are trying to do. You could just assign an ID on the application/client-side first, or in the SQL code that does the insert. Or you could use a `SEQUENCE` per template. Or a random number. Or forget about the whole thing, and just number the rows when you query them.

---

But if you are really set on using a trigger, you need to take account of multiple or zero rows, and you need to take into account even multiple for the same `templateName`. You also need the correct locking on `dbo.myTable`.

So it should look like this.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.setPosition
ON dbo.myTable
AFTER INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)  -- early bailout
    RETURN;

UPDATE t
SET position = others.maxPosition + i.rn
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      -- need to number the inserts in case of multiple per templateName
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.templateName ORDER BY i.id)
    FROM inserted i
) i
JOIN dbo.myTable t ON t.id = i.id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      maxPosition = ISNULL(MAX(position),0)
    FROM dbo.myTable others WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE others.templateName = i.templateName
) others;
```

Ensure that your table is indexed on `templateName` or you will end up with major blocking and deadlocking issues.

Comment: "Or forget about the whole thing, and just number the rows when you query them." As I said we don't care how the data would appear in a query but how they will be inserted with order. Even if there will be a gap after a delete the order will be the same and only that is our concern. Thank you for your post. I will examine it.

Comment: Although my post was also the occasion for another approach to my original problem from others, I accept the answer because it concerns the exact problem I posed and obviously I will also consider the sequence solution which seems attractive to me but now I don't have time.